# Apache 2.2.17 crashes on simple HTML multipart upload (post)

Tags: html, apache2, apache, angstrom-linux, openembedded

Version Apache : 2.2.17  on a linux OpenEmbedded Server .

As soon as file upload via html happens , the webpage hangs

the error_log log  shows the following error

```
[notice] child pid 1141 exit signal Segmentation Fault (11)
```

the pid  1141 in the above text is a httpd (apache) process that crashes ,

Please point out possible changes that need to be made to apache configuration , so that HTML post works  fine .

Comment: I don't think a seg fault can usually be fixed via a configuration change. It sounds like something else is wrong.

Comment: The issue is that 2.2.14 was working . when we upgraded to 2.2.17 and this issue started . I was wondering if upgrading to 2.2.22 would help . But i was not able to find out recipes for 2.2.22(Stable Version). Would you happen to know any ?